# Configure Visual Studio 2019 with UNIX end of lines

Tags: visual-studio-2019, eol, end-of-line

How set unix lf the default end of line in visual studio 2019?  editor is always showing a request for normalize inconsistent line endings.  The extension LineEndingsUnifier has not support for vs2019

Comment: Do you mean https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JakubBielawa.LineEndingsUnifier ? It seems it supports VS2019 now, or at least it’s listed in the «Works with» section.

Comment: it worked for a few days until vs2019 was updated and does not allow Synchronously autoloaded extensions.  Now when loading vs2019 it shows a warning and disables this extension.